# Post to external url is not working using ajax and php curl

Tags: ajax, web-services, forms, php-curl, http-post

I have a web service of a third party CRM. Which is working fine using a html form post

```
 <form method='post' action='http://example.com/myservice/action'>
      <div id='JavascriptWarning' class='warningmessage'>Javascript must be enabled in order to complete this form</div>

      <span class='webformlabel'>Last Name</span>
      <input class='webforminput' name='LastName' type='text'><span class='mandatorymarker'>*</span><br>

      <span class='webformlabel'>First Name</span>
      <input class='webforminput' name='FirstName' type='text'><span class='mandatorymarker'>*</span><br>

<input class='submitbutton' type='submit' id='SubmitButton' value='Submit' disabled='true' onclick='return Validate();'/>
</form>
```

But I want to use it in ajax or php curl post

When I am using ajax there is error message

“No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource”
This is my code

```
function StoreCRMData() {             
          $.ajax({                  
              type: "POST",
              url: "http://example.com/myservice/action",
              data:$('form').serialize(),
              success: function()
              {
                  return false;
              }
          });
      }
```

Also PHP curl is not working

```
<?php
function post_to_url($url, $data) {
   $fields = '';
   foreach($data as $key => $value) { 
      $fields .= $key . '=' . $value . '&'; 
   }
   rtrim($fields, '&');
   $post = curl_init();
   curl_setopt($post, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
   curl_setopt($post, CURLOPT_POST, count($data));
   curl_setopt($post, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields);
   curl_setopt($post, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
   $result = curl_exec($post);
   curl_close($post);
}

$data = array(
   "LastName" => "My First name",
   "FirstName" => "My Last name"

);
post_to_url("http://example.com/myservice/action", $data);
?>
```

Kindly help me how to solve this problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For security reasons, browsers restrict cross-origin HTTP requests initiated from within scripts. ( CORS)

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS

> A resource makes a cross-origin HTTP request when it requests a resource from a different domain than the one which the first resource itself serves.

The server need to add the CORS headers to POST and OPTIONS responses to specifically allow access to the domain in which you are serving the page

For example

```
 Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
 Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, OPTIONS
 Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type
```